# What audio codec do the following application makes use of?

Tags: c#, streaming, voip, audio-streaming, live-streaming

Does anybody know what audio codec do the following VoIP applications make use of for live streaming of voice over IP? I need the above information for experimenting with my own VoIP server/client written in C#.

1. [TeamSpeak](http://teamspeak.com/)
2. [Pfingo](http://www.pfingo.com)
3. Windows Live Messenger
4. Yahoo Messenger

Answer (score 1):

TeamSpeak 3 uses Speex. Never heard of Pfingo, and no idea on the last two.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the first two but the last ones use proprietary protocol.
I suggest, if possible, to do experiments with clients that supports SIP